# How to unit test something like this?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage

I have an example like this which is based on the Laravel key generator:

```
public function generateRandomKey(): string
{
    $generatedKey = base64_encode(random_bytes(16));

    // Encrypt the generated key with our public key so it is not a 'plain password' anymore.
    $value = openssl_public_encrypt($generatedKey, $crypted, $this->getPublicKey());

    if (!$value) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Encryption failed: could not generate a random key.');
    }

    return base64_encode($crypted);
}
```

I would like to unit tests this and I can, expect for my `RuntimeException`. I would like to have 100% code coverage but I also don't want to force scenario's just to get 100% code coverage.

In this example I would would to have PHPUnit hit the exception as well. I can not provide a wrong key because my `getPublicKey()` is private and will throw an error before I get to the error in this method.

Triggering decryption errors is not that hard since I can just supply a random value that has not been properly encrypted.

So how would I be able to test a scenario like this and achieve 100% code coverage. Is this possible or even wise to test something like this or should I rather ignore it with a PHPUnit comment or something?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 100% coverage is your goal then you will need to proceed down the route of potentially "over optimising" your code for the sake of it. In this case it wouldn't be too much of a hit though.

One option is to abstract out the encryption line into its own partially mockable method, however by doing so (and telling PHPUnit what it will return) you're essentially just checking that an exception can be thrown (literally).

Semantically speaking, getter/setter methods would tend to be public - while that's not strictly enforced by any body. I can entirely see why you wouldn't want `getPrivateKey` as part of your API, but you *could* feasibly add a `setPrivateKey` method to your public API - this would solve your unit testing issue:

```
# File: YourClass
public function setPrivateKey(string $key) : YourClass
{
    $this->privateKey = $key;
    return $this;
}
```

Then:

```
# File: YourClassTest
/**
 * @expectedException RuntimeException
 * @expectedExceptionMessage Encryption failed: could not generate a random key.
 */
public function testGenerateRandomKeyThrowsExceptionWhenCannotEncrypt()
{
    $class = new YourClass;
    $class->setPrivateKey('highly-unlikely-to-be-a-valid-private-key');
    $class->generateRandomKey();
}
```

Of course - by doing this you run into the argument that "you should not test code you don't own", i.e. the `openssl` method. This is a trade-off that you'll make to achieve 100% coverage if that's your goal.

Comment: By the way - if your getPrivateKey does it's own validation and throws its own exception you'll need to partially mock it so it doesn't in your test for generateRandomKey

Answer (score 0):

You need to stub `openssl_public_encrypt` to return false.

Assuming your `generateRandomKey` method belongs to class `StephanV`, the test may look like:

```
namespace Tests;

function openssl_public_encrypt()
{
    return false;
}

class StephanVTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @expectedException \RuntimeException
     */
    public function testGenerateRandomKeyThrowsException()
    {
        $cut = new StephanV;
        $cut->generateRandomKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you're basically only testing the logic that says "if false is false then throw an exception"

Comment: @RobbieAverill, I am testing that `generateRandomKey` throws an expected exception when native function returns false.

Comment: Arguably true, yeah - from a public API point of view, which is what you should be testing at the end of the day - I suppose the analogy should be test the end result, not the path to get there (unless the path is also public API)

Comment: Hang on - correct me if I'm wrong in the PHP7 world, but you can't just redeclare native PHP functions like that...?

Comment: @RobbieAverill true, you can not simply re-declare it.

Comment: @RobbieAverill, and Stephan-v, have you tried it? The key point is to namespace it. The simplified proof https://repl.it/FrY3/1

Comment: @AlexBlex right! It would probably be tidier (and more PSR-2 compliant) as a class method though

Comment: @RobbieAverill I doubt wrapping all native function into class methods would be much tidier, but it is out of topic and pretty much matter of taste.